# Python - Add a column to a dataframe containing a value from another row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
+-----+-------+----------+-------+
| No  | Group | refGroup | Value |
+-----+-------+----------+-------+
| 123 | A1    | A1       |   5.0 |
| 123 | B1    | A1       |   7.3 |
| 123 | B2    | A1       |   8.9 |
| 123 | B3    | B1       |   7.9 |
| 465 | A1    | A1       |   1.4 |
| 465 | B1    | A1       |   4.5 |
| 465 | B2    | B1       |   7.3 |
+-----+-------+----------+-------+
```

Now I need to add another column which conatains the difference between the value of column `Value` from the current row and the value of column `Value` from the row with the same number (`No`) and the group (`Group`) that is written in `refGroup`.

Exeption: If `refGroup` equals `Group`, `Value` and `refValue` are the same.

So the result should be:

```
+-----+-------+----------+-------+----------+
| No  | Group | refGroup | Value | refValue |
+-----+-------+----------+-------+----------+
| 123 | A1    | A1       |   5.0 |      5.0 |
| 123 | B1    | A1       |   7.3 |      2.3 |
| 123 | B2    | A1       |   8.9 |      3.9 |
| 123 | B3    | B1       |   7.9 |      0.6 |
| 465 | A1    | A1       |   1.4 |      1.4 |
| 465 | B1    | A1       |   4.5 |      3.1 |
| 465 | B2    | B1       |   7.3 |      2.8 |
+-----+-------+----------+-------+----------+
```

Explanation for the first two rows:

First row: `refGroup` equals `Group` -> `refValue` = `Value`

Second row: search for the row with the same `No` (123) and `refGroup` as `Group` (A1) and calculate `Value` of the current row minus `Value` of the referenced row (7.3 - 5.0 = 2.3).

I thought I might need to use groupby() and apply(), but how?

Hope my example is detailed enough, if you need any further information, please ask :)

Comment: How about you use [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), try to find what output you get or the errors and then post or edit your question?

Comment: @MaMo Can you please describe the `0.6` result. I see that you do `7.9-7.3` but im wondering why you use `7.3` since `B1` isn't equal to `A1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a database SQL like technique; use 'self-join' with `merge`.  You merge/join a dataframe to itself using `left_on` and  `right_on` to line up 'Group' with 'refGroup' then subtract the value from each dataframe record:

```
df_out = df.merge(df, 
                  left_on=['No','refGroup'], 
                  right_on=['No','Group'], 
                  suffixes=('','_ref'))

df['refValue'] = np.where(df_out['Group'] == df_out['refGroup'],
                          df_out['value'],
                          df_out['value'] - df_out['value_ref'])

df
```

Output:

```
    No Group refGroup  value  refValue
0  123    A1       A1    5.0       5.0
1  123    B1       A1    7.3       2.3
2  123    B2       A1    8.9       3.9
3  123    B3       B1    7.9       0.6
4  465    A1       A1    1.4       1.4
5  465    B1       A1    4.5       3.1
6  465    B2       B1    7.3       2.8
```

Comment: amazing! My dataframe is huge but this solution only takes about one second, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

With comprehension list you could do:

```
df['refValue'] = [ row['Value'] - float(df.loc[(df['No']==row['No']) & (df['Group']==row['refGroup']),'Value'].values) if row['refGroup']!=row['Group'] else row['Value'] for index, row in df.iterrows() ]
```

Comment: Your solution works fine but running time has a high dependency on the size of the dataframe (needs more than 10 minutes for my dataframe with about 60.000 rows)

Comment: Yes it’s not the most efficient way.